# Machine learning Interview programming test

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning

I am actually solving a small programming test which has been submitted to me before an actual interview.

I had to actually remove the information about the problem, you can easily find it in below links.

So I tried several intuitive approaches to this, with more or less success.
During some researches, I found an exemple on GIT (https://github.com/miracode/Machine-Works) where some nodes are being used.
I decided to implement it into my script to test it.
It turns out to be much faster than mine, but cannot still handle the whole Input set. This one is a 25MB txt file with 54 different cases, some of them with 10 000+ machines per TestCases.
And I found this same solution (and only this one) on other GIT solutions to this problem.

So when I was running my own script, I could understand it would crash my PC before ending the big input test, but taking a solution from GIT and not being able to compute the test input is quite surprising.

I have 16GB of RAM on my computer and I never saw it crash like that, even when handling way bigger datasets.

Here is a copy of my implementation of their solution :

```
from load_input2 import load as load
import time
"""Third version of project """
""" Implementing decision object, inspired from GIT-found script """

PATH = 'input2.txt'


class TestCase(object):
    def __init__(self, C, D, machines=[]):
        self.budget = C
        self.days = D
        self.machines = sorted([Machine(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3])
                         for i in machines], key = lambda x : x.day)

    def run(self):
        choice = Decision()
        (choice.machine, choice.budget, choice.day) = (None, self.budget, 0)

        choices = [choice, ]

        for machine in self.machines:

            next_choice = []
            for choice in choices:
                choice.to_buy, choice.not_buy = Decision(), Decision()
                choice.to_buy.day, choice.not_buy.day = machine.day, machine.day
                potential_budget = choice.budget + choice.machine.p_sell + choice.machine.daily_profit * \
                    (machine.day - choice.day -
                     1) if choice.machine else choice.budget

                if machine.p_buy <= potential_budget:

                    choice.to_buy.budget = potential_budget - machine.p_buy
                    choice.to_buy.machine = machine
                    next_choice.append(choice.to_buy)

                choice.not_buy.machine = choice.machine

                try:
                    choice.not_buy.budget = choice.budget + \
                        choice.machine.daily_profit * \
                        (machine.day - choice.day)
                except AttributeError:
                    choice.not_buy.budget = choice.budget
                next_choice.append(choice.not_buy)

            choices = next_choice


        results = []
        for choice in choices:
            try:
                results.append(choice.budget +
                               choice.machine.daily_profit *
                               (self.days -
                                choice.day) +
                               choice.machine.p_sell)
            except AttributeError:
                results.append(choice.budget)
        return(max(results))


class Machine(object):
    def __init__(self, day, p_buy, p_sell, daily_profit):
        self.p_buy, self.p_sell = p_buy, p_sell
        self.day, self.daily_profit = day, daily_profit


class Decision(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.to_buy, self.not_buy = None, None
        self.machine, self.budget = None, None
        self.day = None


def main():
    start = time.time()
    global PATH
    testcases = load(PATH)
    count = 1
    for (case_data, data) in testcases:
        machines = [i for i in data]
        dolls = TestCase(case_data[2], case_data[3], machines).run()
        print(
            "Case {}: {}".format(case_data[0], dolls))
    print("Effectue en  ", start - time.time())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Load_input2.py :

```
def load(path):
    with open(path) as fil:
        inp = fil.read().split('\n')  # Opening the input file
    testcases, results = {}, {}
    count = 1
    for line in inp:  # Splitting it and getting results for each TestCase
        split = [int(i) for i in line.split()]
        if len(split) == 3:
            case = tuple([count]+split)
            testcases[case] = []
            count+=1
        else:
            if len(split) > 0:
                testcases[case].append(split)
    sort = sorted([(case,data) for case,data in testcases.items()] , key = lambda x : x[0][0])
    #print([i[0] for i in sort])
    return(sort)
```

If you have any advice or hint, I am up for them !

I don't really want a ready-to-paste solution since this is an interview question and I want it to sincerely reflect my capacities, even though I do include in my capacities the one of searching in amazing communities ;)

Thanks for caring !

---

EDIT : The whole Input test set is available here : https://gitlab.com/InfoCode/Coding_Problems/raw/master/MachineWork/input.txt

---

EDIT : Original script I use, certainly non-optimal but with much less computations I believe on really big testcase 
Process is different , explained in beginning

```
""" First version of the project"""
""" Using a day-to-day approach to estimate best behavior"""
""" On each day, this algorithm will complete :"""
""" - Looking for each machine to be bought on this day and taking the more profitable one in long-term run"""
""" - During all depreciation period (time required for the machine to be cost-effective), checking if the purchase of the machine won't interfer with some more profitable machine"""
""" - Buying the machine and moving along to next day"""
""" This algorithm allow a faster execution for input with large sets of machines to be sold"""

""" Cannot yet found how to prevent him from choosing the machine 2 in case (6,10,20) which leads to a decrease of 1 dollar in profits"""

PATH = 'input2.txt'

# Defining the TestCase class which is used for iterating through the days


class TestCase(object):
    def __init__(self, C, D, machines=[]):
        self.budget = C
        self.days = D
        self.machines = [Machine(self, i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3])
                         for i in machines]
        self.choices = []

    # Main function for running the iteration through the days
    def run_case(self):
        for i in range(1, self.days + 1):
            best = self.best_machine_on_day(i)
            if (best is not None and self.should_buy(best[0], i)):
                self.choices.append(best)
        if len(self.choices) > 0:
            self.choices[-1][0].buy_sell(self, self.days + 1, sell=True)
        return(self.budget)

    # Function to define the best machine on a specific day
    def best_machine_on_day(self, n):
        results = []
        for machine in self.machines:
            if n == machine.day:
                results.append(machine.day_based_potential(self, n))
        if len(results) == 0:
            return(None)
        elif len(results) == 1:
            return(results[0])
        else:
            return(max(results, key=lambda x: x[2] * (self.days - n) - x[1]))

    # To define rather an individual should buy or not a machine having a
    # small look on the day aheads
    def should_buy(self, machine, n):
        potential_budget = self.budget + self.choices[-1][0].p_sell + self.choices[-1][0].daily_profit * (
            n - self.choices[-1][0].day - 1) if len(self.choices) > 0 else self.budget
        day_to_cover_cost = int(
            machine.cost / machine.daily_profit) if machine.cost % machine.daily_profit != 0 else machine.cost / machine.daily_profit - 1
        for day in range(day_to_cover_cost):
            next_day = self.best_machine_on_day(n + day + 1)
            if next_day is not None:
                day_to_buy = next_day[0].day
                if (
                    machine.earnings_from_day(
                        self, day_to_buy) < next_day[0].earnings_from_day(
                        self, day_to_buy) or machine.cost >= machine.daily_profit * (
                        next_day[0].day - machine.day)) and next_day[0].p_buy <= potential_budget:
                    return(False)
        if (potential_budget >= machine.p_buy and machine.earnings_from_day(
                self, n) >= machine.p_buy):
            if len(self.choices) > 0:
                self.choices[-1][0].buy_sell(self, n, sell=True)
            machine.buy_sell(self, n)
            return(True)
        else:
            return(False)

# Defining the machine object


class Machine(object):
    def __init__(self, case, day, p_buy, p_sell, daily_profit):
        self.cost = p_buy - p_sell
        self.p_buy, self.p_sell = p_buy, p_sell
        self.day = day
        self.daily_profit = daily_profit

    # To compute the earnings from a starting day n to the end
    def earnings_from_day(self, case, n):
        if self.day <= n <= case.days:
            return((case.days - n) * self.daily_profit - self.cost)
        else:
            return(0)
    # Represent itself method

    def day_based_potential(self, case, n):
        return((self, self.cost, self.daily_profit))
    # Actions on Budget

    def buy_sell(self, case, n, sell=False):
        if sell:
            case.budget += self.p_sell + self.daily_profit * (n - self.day - 1)
        else:
            case.budget -= self.p_buy


def main():
    global PATH
    testcases = load(PATH)
    count = 1
    for case_data, data in testcases.items():
        machines = [i for i in data]
        dolls = TestCase(case_data[1], case_data[2], machines).run_case()
        print(
            "Case {}: {}".format(count, dolls))
        count += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Did you happen to find the solution (i.e. the resulting total budget) for each test case from your input file somewhere online?

Comment: I didn't , I made up my own using machines processing before running the test case (looking for the profitable one and removing the others) and I updated the nodes registered every 10 steps, taking the 20 more profitable (those parameters might be changed). It runs the whole input set but it gives some sub optimal solution for the cases needing more strategic choices of machines to maximise the profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update: Solution

I found that this problem origins from the 2011 ACM-ICPC World Finals (acm International Collegiate Programming Contest; https://icpc.baylor.edu/worldfinals/problems, Problem F). They also provide the correct results to test against.

http://www.csc.kth.se/~austrin/icpc/finals2011solutions.pdf

In my approach, I followed a two-step approach:

1. Some pre-processing is applied to all machines available in one test case. The pre-processing over-estimates the affordability of each machine given a upper-bound heuristic of all prior machines. Machines that will never be affordable are pruned from the set.
2. The search itself follows a recursive scheme from back to front. It first identifies the most desirable machine (the one that generates the highest profit from its day of availability until the end of the period) and follows a DFS (depth-first search) to find a path using affordable machines to the initial budget. Since machines are re-assessed each step, we can consider the solution optimal as soon as we find one.

I may post my solution here once I come up with the correct results in all test cases.

### Original Answer

For your task: It seems as if it is *made to break*, i.e. it is not fully computable. You may need heuristics for a directed search with prospective planning (and a plan-ahead window of `n` days) to efficiently come near the solution.

Concerning reading that entire file, what about using a generator expression while keeping the file handle open?
Like so:

```
def as_int_list(line):
    return [int(i) for i in line.strip().split()]


def read_test_case(filehandle):
    n, c, d = tuple(as_int_list(fh.readline()))
    m = []
    while len(m) < n:
        m.append(as_int_list(fh.readline()))
    yield (n, c, d, m)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    localfile = 'testcases.txt'

    no = 0
    with open(localfile, 'r') as fh:
        while no < 5:
            case = read_test_case(fh).next()
            print(case)
            no += 1
```

Note that I restricted the number of test cases to be read to `5`, but you can read until `EOFError` or `StopIteration` (haven't tested for the entire file, but you'll surely find out).

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using the generator expression, I though it was better to close the file asap, but when I think about it , I realize I was occupying some memory anyway by saving all the inputs in a variable, so I think I do understand the interest of your method, just using a bit of memory for each testcase and cleaning, right ?
For the directed search, this was somehow one of my first scripts, I was using a plan-ahead window of the numbers of days needed by the machine to cover its cost , but I let this one go cause it was not optimal, far less computing however, I put it in an edit

Comment: Forget about the first script idea, not better anyhow ...
Looking for a more large directed search ..

Comment: Ok I came out with an idea quite working : 
For TestCase with large number of machines, every n machines, I ask him to sort all possible cases/nodes and to take the one with best potential profit to come
For instance, if I do it every 10 machines, at the tenth one, it will take all the nodes created , 2^9 and will sort them depending on profit, keeping only the 10th best and will do 10 next machines with the 10 best instead of the 2^9 , that alllows me to put an upper bound to my nodes number : 2^n , avoiding very large and useless computations
Any thought about it ?

Comment: I think you shouldn't try to completely calculate it day-wise, but rather search for a more intelligent solution that prunes branches of the search tree. I have a (mostly) working solution, but am unsure whether or not to solve your interview test...

Comment: I changed my solution as I said in my answer to your comment in my original post. I submitted my solution anyway for the interview so I can have a look to yours with pleasure and without trouble regarding my interview (which I'm having later today btw).